# Sending some lines from server in python to QT(C++) client

Tags: python, qt, sockets, send

Ia have serwer in Python on my Raspberry Pi and Android application in QT (C++). I wan to send some data (lines) from my serwer (from csv file) to client application and save it in QListWidget. Client can connect by Bluetooth or TCP (I created 2 servers on RPi).

I tried to send line by line in loop, beacuse I don't know if it's any way to send whole list or something like that. I reade about pickle in Python, but I don't know if I can read this in QT.

Client in QT:

```
if(typ=="BT") line = sBT->readLine();
if(typ=="TCP") line = sTCP->readLine();
line = line.trimmed();
while(line!="koniec")
{
 ui->wflista->addItem(line);
 if(typ=="BT") line = sBT->readLine();
 if(typ=="TCP") line = sTCP->readLine();
 line = line.trimmed();
}
```

Server in Python:

```
if(data=="logi"):
   globalvar.conn.send("logi\n")
   print("Klient pyta o logi")
   with open('/home/pi/Projekt/log.csv', 'rb') as logi:
       csvreader = csv.reader(logi, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
       for row in csvreader:
          globalvar.conn.send(' - '.join(row)+"\n")
          print('-'.join(row) +"\n")
       globalvar.conn.send("koniec")
       print("Wyslalem wszystko")
```

I would like to get lines from file on RPi to my QListWidget (wflista), but unfortunatelly something is wrong.

When Itry to do it, server display every line from csv file and "Wysłałem wszystko", so it ended loop. on client side QListWidget is empty and it jams. I think that it is in infinite loop, beacuse it can't read "koniec" (argument of while loop.

If I change this argument from "koniec" to "" it sometimes does nothing, sometimes gets lines as it should or sometimes gets only a part of it and part is lost.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Do you maybe need to add "\n" to the string at the end of `globalvar.conn.send("koniec")`? I don't know if your `send()` function will add that automatically or not (looking at the other code it seems like not). `readLine()` will not detect a line w/out a line ending being present.  Also seems like maybe you want a `canReadLine()` in there somewhere (to check if socket actually has data).. but maybe not.

Comment: Ok, I knew about "\n" it's my mistake. Unfortunatelly it changes nothing... I tried something and I noticed that when I add a QMessageBox in while loop it works... J must click Ok i messageboxes, but when I do it in my QListWidgets appears new element. And loop ends. What it means? it reads to fast? Needs something like wait or what?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this on the C++ side instead and see what happens? (This would be instead of the whole C++ example block you posted in the question.)

```
QIODevice *sock = (typ == "BT" ? qobject_cast<QIODevice*>(sBT) : qobject_cast<QIODevice*>(sTCP));
while (sock->canReadLine()) {
  line = sock->readLine();
  line = line.trimmed();
  ui->wflista->addItem(line);
}
```

P.S. I assume this part is being triggered by a signal from the socket, like `readyRead()`, or is placed after a `waitForReadyRead()`.

**ADDED**:  Debug code:

```
QIODevice *sock = (typ == "BT" ? qobject_cast<QIODevice*>(sBT) : qobject_cast<QIODevice*>(sTCP));
while (sock->bytesAvailable()) {
  const QByteArray data = sock->readAll();
  qDebug() << data << '\n' << data.toHex(':');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's rriggered by readyRead(). It's the situation: client push button, it send's command to serwer and server sens command thats trigger this block of code.

I tried to use your code, but unfortunatelly I have an error:
"incompatible operand types ('QBluetoothSocket *' and 'QTcpSocket *')
            QIODevice *sock = (typ == "BT" ? sBT : sTCP);
                                           ^ ~~~   ~~~~"

Comment: Right, sorry, that needs a cast or to be broken up into multiple lines. I edited the code, try it now.

Comment: OK, after your edit it works, but not alvays... Sometimes it reads ony a part of data or even nothing.

Comment: Nothing (how do you know)? Or do you mean it prints a blank line? Anyway I think you'll need to debug further to see what you're actually getting over the socket. I added a simple example (use instead of the `readLine()` code). The `toHex()` dump is just to help examine the contents more precisely.

Comment: Ok, I used this debug code and I noticed 3 types of result.
First - I think when all is OK: in the debug appears all lines 
Second - Appears lines and then uncompletted line for example: line\nline\nline\nlin
And third - something like this: "D libZamek.so:  "31:34:3a:36:42:3a:37:32:3a:39:44:3a:31:30:3a:32:42:28:4f:75:6b:69:74:65:6c:29:20:2d:20:53:70:72:61:77:64:7a:65:6e:69:65:20:73:74:61:6e:75:20:72:79:67:6c:61:20:2d:20:64:2e:30:39:2e:32:30:31:39:2c:20:31:33:3a:33:34:3a:33:39:0a:31:34:3a:36:42:3a:37:32:3a:39:44:3a:31:30:3a:32:42:28:4f:75:6b:69:74:65:6c:29:20:2d:20:53:70:72:61:77:64

Comment: Well if you can't reliably get the full line on each read then you'll need to buffer the data until it is all received (eg. `QBuffer` or just appending to a `QByteArray`) and split it into lines afterwards (if you need it in lines at all). That's probably a good idea anyway since socket transmissions could get delayed at any point. You could also check for timeout that way. As for the "D libZamek.so"...? If that's not actually being sent by your server then it looks like memory corruption somewhere along the line. What platform is the C++ part running on, and which sockets are you using?

Comment: C++ part is on Android. I use QTcpSocket at this and socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) in Python on Raspberry.

How is with buffer, I had never do this :/